# Self-organising Neural Network - Looking for litterature

Tags: neural-networks, references, algorithms

I am looking at developing an algorithm that would automatically grow the structure of a neural network by adding/deleting units within a layer, or adding layers as necessary.

I researched the topic and only found literature from before 2000. I was somewhat aware of it, being old enough to have come across some of them when they were published. What I found is mostly interested in neuron-by-neuron construction. I didn't find anything layer-by-layer.

I have searched for more recent papers, including in the deep learning space and have drawn a blank.

I wrote a draft blog article laying out my thoughts (https://emmanuel-r8.github.io/post/neural-network-incremental-growth.html). I will carry on researching the topic. But I am looking for references that would tell me that it is either a blind alley or expand my horizons.

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful: [https://www.amazon.com/SORN-Self-Organizing-Recurrent-Neural-Network-ebook/dp/B00X1FIHCO](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00X1FIHCO)
And this : https://pypi.org/project/sorn/

Comment: Thank you. One of the citations also looks interesting: https://papers.nips.cc/paper/3394-self-organization-using-synaptic-plasticity

Comment: More generally, NIPS has quite a few more references (although not quite on point. But no doubt I'll find many ideas!): https://papers.nips.cc/search/?q=self-organizing

Comment: Could you give full references in case the links go dead in the future? Short summaries of the content of each would be helpful, too. Thank you.

Comment: I made the comment based on the papers' title. I'll comment more when I have read the papers.